# NodeJS video streaming in html not working for videos of large size

Tags: html, node.js, video

I am using NodeJS to stream videos through html using the following code :

```
var fs = require("fs"),
http = require("http"),
url = require("url"),
path = require("path");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url != "/movie.mp4") {
   res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
   res.end('<video src="http://localhost:8888/movie.mp4" controls>    </video>');
 } else {
var file = path.resolve(__dirname,"movie.mp4");
fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      // 404 Error if file not found
      return res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  res.end(err);
  }
  var range = req.headers.range;
  if (!range) {
   // 416 Wrong range
   return res.sendStatus(416);
  }
  var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
  var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
  var total = stats.size;
  var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
  var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

  res.writeHead(206, {
    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": chunksize,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  });

  var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: start, end: end })
    .on("open", function() {
      stream.pipe(res);
      }).on("error", function(err) {
      res.end(err);
       });
   });
 }
  }).listen(8888);
```

I am able to stream videos of size upto 50MB, but when I stream a video of size 350MB of duration 90 seconds it buffers and takes too much time to load. If the same can be achieved using socket ? Or is there a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Video streaming is a specialist area if you want to achieve high quality - there are mechanisms to adjust the bit rate to the network conditions and to ensure fast video start initially for example.

Given the complexity it is usually easier to use a dedicated streaming server - there are several open source ones available, for example:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org